# ffmpeg audio property is blank in output video

Tags: image, video, ffmpeg

Here's what I have to do,
I want to convert two different images in different video file (ex: convert a.jpg into a.avi and b.jpg into b.avi).

I am trying to generate video (.avi) from image file. Video file is generated successfully but I can't see the audio properties when I right click on video and see details tab in property.

Then I have one video file (.avi), using ffmpeg concat function, I am concating these three video files (a.avi, middle.avi which I already have, b.avi).
After this, I am getting file output.avi but audio is not there in outout.avi file. I have middle.avi which already contains audio.

Here's my concat command,

```
ffmpeg -i "concat:a.avi|middle.avi|b.avi" -vcodec copy 103_n4_2.avi
```

I am trying to generate video (.avi) from only one image file. Video file is generated successfully but I can't see the audio properties when I right click on video and see details tab in property.

Here's my command to convert image to video:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i bCopy.jpg -t 30 -q:v 0 -r 24 output_a.avi
```

PS: a.avi and b.avi (which I have generated from images does not contain audio) but only middle.avi contains the audio.

Answer (score 1):

I think the audio track is completly ommitted. I was not able to test it but it seams you need to map the audio stream manually to the output and delay it by the the length of your first image.

```
ffmpeg -i middle.avi -itsoffset 1 -map 1:1 -i "concat:a.avi|middle.avi|b.avi" -map 0:0 -vcodec copy  -acodec copy 103_n4_2.avi
```

Comment: Ok, so you mean if I execute this command, i will get audio in output video?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help but I have found the solution of this perticular issue,

Here are the steps:

```
1. Generate blank mp3 of the first slide duration.
    - ffmpeg -f lavfi -i aevalsrc=0 -t 31 -q:a 9 -acodec libmp3lame out.mp3

2. Trim audio from middle slide
    - ffmpeg -i middle.avi -acodec copy middle.mp3

3. Concat this two audio
    - ffmpeg -i "concat:out.mp3|middle.mp3" -acodec copy 103_n4_2.mp3

4. Now concat audio and video(that we've cgenerated by concatenation)
    - ffmpeg -i 103_n4_3.avi -i 103_n4_2.mp3 -c:v copy -c:a aac -strict experimental 103_n4_5.avi
```